How can I get the result of this forest?
In this code,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\newcommand\engnum[1]{\ifcase#1
%zero
\or
%one
\or 
%two
\or
%three
\or
Probability
\or
Result
\or
six
\or
seven
\or
eight
\or
nine
\fi}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            % nodes
            draw, rounded corners=2pt,
            where level=0{circle}{minimum width=3em},
            top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
            math content,
alias/.wrap pgfmath arg={l-#1}{level},
            % tree
            grow'=east,
edge = {-Stealth},
            edge=semithick,
            child anchor=west,
            l sep=12mm,
            s sep=10mm,
            where level=1{s sep=10mm}{},% insert different `s sep`
            tier/.option = level,
            /tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
                pos=0.5, sloped, node font=\footnotesize,
                inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1},
            EL/.style = {if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
                    edge label={node[ELS=south]{$#1$}}}
                {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$#1$}}}}
        },
        [\text{Start}
        [A,     EL=\num{0.2}
        [B,     EL=\num{0.7},[AB,
[EL=\num{0.2}\times \num{0.7} = \num{0.14}]]
]
        [\overline{B},   EL=\num{0.3},
[A\overline{B},[ EL=\num{0.2}\times\num{0.3}=\num{0.06}]]
]
        ]
        [\overline{A},   EL=\num{0.8}
        [B,     EL=\num{0.15},[\overline{A}B,[ EL=\num{0.8}\times\num{0.15}]]]
        [\overline{B},   EL=\num{0.85},[\overline{A} \,\overline{B},[ EL=\num{0.8}\times\num{0.85}]]]
        ]
        ]
\path ([yshift=0.5ex]current bounding box.north) coordinate (N);
% 0.5ex can be changed to increase/decreas the vertical distance between the
% level indicators and the tree
\foreach \X  in {0,...,4}
{\node[anchor=south west,font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily] at 
(l-\X.west|-N){\engnum{\the\numexpr\X+1}};}
    \end{forest}
\end{document} 

I use
EL=\num{0.2}\times \num{0.7} = \num{0.14}, EL=\num{0.2}\times\num{0.3}=\num{0.06}, ... But I only get EL. How can I get the above results. And how to get a ractangle with any width?

And how can I put the word Probability at center of level 3 and Result at the  center of level 4


Off-topic: don't put where in for tree. Either bring it out or use if. (where works but it parses the tree completely at least n times, where n is the number of nodes in the tree, rather than once.

Are you trying to set the content of the nodes or the edge labels? Because EL seems to be for the latter, but you are using that in the node itself.

Edit addresses new question concerning the level labels' alignment.
Please don't edit questions after you have answers which address the original. Fortunately, in this case, it is an easy adjustment.
It isn't clear whether you want to apply the EL style to edge labels for empty terminal nodes or whether you want to apply the same style to the content of those nodes or something else.
If you say
[EL=\num{0.4}\times\num{0.9}]

EL is not interpreted as a style at all. Rather this is interpreted as the content of the node. But the = causes problems for the parser, so only EL is typeset. To avoid this, you'd need
[{EL=\num{0.4}\times\num{0.9}}]

but I somehow doubt that's the desideratum. More likely, you want \num{0.4}... in the edge label or as the content of the node without EL= etc.
By way of example, I assume you want output like this:

To do this, we define a new style ELT={<num>}{<num>}. We use the two values to construct the edge label as before. Then we use pgfmath to calculate their product and format it as the node's content.
We also tweak the content of all nodes slightly to prevent wonky arrows due to different heights.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\newcommand\engnum[1]{\ifcase#1
  %zero
  \or
  %one
  \or 
  %two
  \or
  %three
  \or
  Probability
  \or
  Result
  \or
  six
  \or
  seven
  \or
  eight
  \or
  nine
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    % nodes
    draw, rounded corners=2pt,
    if level=0{circle}{minimum width=3em},
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    math content,
    alias/.wrap pgfmath arg={l-#1}{level},
    % tree
    grow'=east,
    edge = {-Stealth,semithick},
    child anchor=west,
    l sep'=12mm,
    if level=1{s sep'=10mm}{s sep'=10mm},% insert different `s sep`
    tier/.option = level,
  },
  for leaves={!u.l sep'+=5mm},
  /tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
    pos=0.5, sloped, font=\footnotesize,
    inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1},
  EL/.style = {%
    if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
      edge label={node[ELS=south]{$#1$}}}
    {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$#1$}}},
  },
  ELT/.style 2 args = {%
    if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
      edge label={node[ELS=south]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}}
    {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}},
    if n children=0{%
      delay={content={\pgfmathparse{(#1*#2)}\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{fixed,precision=2}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}}},
    }{},
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    for descendants={content+={\llap{\phantom{$\overline{X}$}}}},
  }
  [\text{Start}
    [A,     EL=\num{0.2}
      [B,     EL=\num{0.7},
        [AB,
          [,ELT={0.2}{0.7} %= \num{0.14}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [\overline{B},   EL=\num{0.3},
        [A\overline{B},
          [, ELT={0.2}{0.3}%=\num{0.06}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [\overline{A},   EL=\num{0.8}
      [B,     EL=\num{0.15}
        [\overline{A}B
          [, ELT={0.8}{0.15}]
        ]
      ]
      [\overline{B},   EL=\num{0.85}
        [\overline{A} \,\overline{B}
          [, ELT={0.8}{0.85}]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \path ([yshift=1.5ex]current bounding box.north) coordinate (N);
  % 0.5ex can be changed to increase/decreas the vertical distance between the
  % level indicators and the tree
  \foreach \X  in {0,...,4}
  {\node[anchor=base,font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily] at 
    (l-\X.center |-N){\engnum{\the\numexpr\X+1}};}
\end{forest}
\end{document}

You could also collect this information from earlier nodes. In fact, strictly speaking, you only really need to specify the content and labels for the first two levels (beyond the root). The final two levels could then be automatically generated as their content is wholly determined.
Edit
You can control other aspects of the way the number is printed using other keys under /pgf/number format. To use commas instead of dots as decimal separators, for example, add use comma. To read input which uses commas, add read comma as period (but note that the manual warns this can have unintended effects as commas have obvious potential to confuse the parser if care isn't taken).
Here's the same tree with no changes to input, but the tweak to the output requested in the comments.

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\newcommand\engnum[1]{\ifcase#1
  %zero
  \or
  %one
  \or 
  %two
  \or
  %three
  \or
  Probability
  \or
  Result
  \or
  six
  \or
  seven
  \or
  eight
  \or
  nine
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    % nodes
    draw, rounded corners=2pt,
    if level=0{circle}{minimum width=3em},
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    math content,
    alias/.wrap pgfmath arg={l-#1}{level},
    % tree
    grow'=east,
    edge = {-Stealth,semithick},
    child anchor=west,
    l sep'=12mm,
    if level=1{s sep'=10mm}{s sep'=10mm},% insert different `s sep`
    tier/.option = level,
  },
  for leaves={!u.l sep'+=5mm},
  /tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
    pos=0.5, sloped, font=\footnotesize,
    inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1},
  EL/.style = {%
    if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
      edge label={node[ELS=south]{$#1$}}}
    {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$#1$}}},
  },
  ELT/.style 2 args = {%
    if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
      edge label={node[ELS=south]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}}
    {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}},
    if n children=0{%
      delay={content={\pgfmathparse{(#1*#2)}\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{fixed,precision=2,use comma}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}}},
    }{},
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    for descendants={content+={\llap{\phantom{$\overline{X}$}}}},
  }
  [\text{Start}
    [A,     EL=\num{0.2}
      [B,     EL=\num{0.7},
        [AB,
          [,ELT={0.2}{0.7} %= \num{0.14}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [\overline{B},   EL=\num{0.3},
        [A\overline{B},
          [, ELT={0.2}{0.3}%=\num{0.06}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [\overline{A},   EL=\num{0.8}
      [B,     EL=\num{0.15}
        [\overline{A}B
          [, ELT={0.8}{0.15}]
        ]
      ]
      [\overline{B},   EL=\num{0.85}
        [\overline{A} \,\overline{B}
          [, ELT={0.8}{0.85}]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \path ([yshift=1.5ex]current bounding box.north) coordinate (N);
  % 0.5ex can be changed to increase/decreas the vertical distance between the
  % level indicators and the tree
  \foreach \X  in {0,...,4}
  {\node[anchor=base,font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily] at 
    (l-\X.center |-N){\engnum{\the\numexpr\X+1}};}
\end{forest}
\end{document}


@cfr I am sorry about this comment, I use output-decimal-marker={,}. How can I get  the result 0,14 instead of 0.14.

@cfr I only want output. I used \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}  only output doesn't get comma.

@JohnPaulPeter Please see edit. I found it easier to use pgfmath here, so we need to tweak /pgf/number format instead. (I think I had trouble getting \num{} to work here.)

@cfr Thank you very much.

@minhthien_2016 you know where the site chat room is? go to the top right menu and click on it. it should show you this site and the meta site. there will also be a link for chat. that takes you to a page with chat rooms.  TeX, LaTeX and Friends is the main site chat room. Click on it. type @cfr ping into the box at the bottom. I can't ping you because you haven't been there (recently), but you should be able to ping me.
